# Cannot run first project under flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Mac with Mojave
Flutter installed
Flutter Doctor passed all the tests

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I started IntelliJ IDE, and clicked on create new project

I selected the Android Emulator: Nexus 5S, and the emulator opened up properly.

I clicked on the green arrow to run, but I got the following error message:

```
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- In the 'General' tab, make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trust

For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/
  AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Finished with error: No development certificates available to code sign app for device deployment
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like its trying to run on an ios device that doesn't have a valid certificate? (flutter doctor is saying there are 2 devices connected)

Comment: Duh, yes. I had my iPhone connected to my Mac. I disconnected by iPhone, and it's now running. If you convert this into an answer, I will credit you

Comment: done, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to run on an ios device that doesn't have a valid certificate. Flutter doctor is saying there are 2 devices connected. If you have an ios device attached to your computer, try disconnecting it so that flutter doesn't try to use it instead of the emulator.

Comment: I get the same error even though I'm connected to the emulator.